# Reading html file on basic web server

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read an html file with Node.js basic server. The code has three options, first two just write some text in the browser on DEV port 3000, the third one should retrieve an html file.

The first two function correctly, also the third one functions when passing in a text. So the error should be in reading the file. I have it in a folder called "static", I get no errors when running in browser so it should have the right path.

I have encountered this a few times now, that I am not able to read html files in the browser through Node.js. Do I still have an error in my code or is this more of a system error? Has anyone else encountered this before? What should I do?

My code..

```
// CREATING A HTTP SERVER USING HTTP MODULE 
// request is the http call, response is the text or file back..
const http_mod = require("http");
const file_sys = require("fs");
const server = http_mod.createServer((req, res) => {

    if (req.url === '/index'){

        // this is the response     
        res.write("hello world from index");
    }

    else if (req.url === '/check'){

        // this is the response     
        res.write("hello world from check");
    }

    else if (req.url === '/'){

        // this is the response     
        // res.write("hello world from main");

        // let know what data to expect 
        // you can use http status codes to explicitly state meaning of status code 
        const readStream = file_sys.createReadStream("./static/test.html");
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/html'});
        readStream.pipe(res);

    }

    // .end sends the response 
    res.end();

// port to listen on 
}).listen("3000");
```

Comment: `.pipe(res)` will transfer the data from the read stream to the write stream and call end when the read stream ends, there is no need to use `res.end()` after.

Comment: YES! Thanks ambianBeing! I was struggling with this for a while..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ending the response `res.end()` before completion of the stream.
using `readStream.on('finish',function(){ res.end(); })` will also work.

```
// CREATING A HTTP SERVER USING HTTP MODULE 
// request is the http call, response is the text or file back..
const http_mod = require("http");
const file_sys = require("fs");
const server = http_mod.createServer((req, res) => {

    if (req.url === '/index'){

        // this is the response     
        res.write("hello world from index");
        res.end();
    }

    else if (req.url === '/check'){

        // this is the response     
        res.write("hello world from check");
        res.end();
    }

    else if (req.url === '/'){

        // this is the response     
        // res.write("hello world from main");

        // let know what data to expect 
        // you can use http status codes to explicitly state meaning of status code 
        const readStream = file_sys.createReadStream("test.html");
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/html'});
        readStream.pipe(res);
    }




// port to listen on 
}).listen("3000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) instead? Read the static html file and write it in the result as string, just like you do in the other two routes (options):

```
// CREATING A HTTP SERVER USING HTTP MODULE 
// request is the http call, response is the text or file back..
const http_mod = require("http");
const file_sys = require("fs");
const server = http_mod.createServer((req, res) => {

    if (req.url === '/index'){

        // this is the response     
        res.write("hello world from index");
    }

    else if (req.url === '/check'){

        // this is the response     
        res.write("hello world from check");
    }

    else if (req.url === '/'){

        // this is the response     
        // res.write("hello world from main");

        // let know what data to expect 
        // you can use http status codes to explicitly state meaning of status code 
        const html = file_sys.readFileSync("./static/test.html");
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/html'});
        res.write(html)

    }

    // .end sends the response 
    res.end();

// port to listen on 
}).listen("3000");
```

Comment: You could do it like this for this example.. I am using Streams here to make sure every file gets read.. Streams uses chunking, for bigger files readFileSync will block.. So using Streams would be preferable over using Static way because of buffer limits on the computer..